# Did Kubrick borrow the idea for the iconic penultimate scene in Dr. Strangelove?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, stanley-kubrick, dr-strangelove

The iconic penultimate scene of [*Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057012/) (1964) has Major Kong (Slim Pickens) manually unlatch the bomb bay doors of his B-52 and drop out of the plane on the bomb that is immediately released, riding it down to its detonation.

[image: Major T.J. "King" Kong yells and waves his hat as he drops out of the bomber on top of the hydrogen bomb]

This scene does not occur in [*Two Hours to Doom*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?18192) (released in the U.S. as *Red Alert*), the [1958 novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Alert_(novel)) by Peter Bryant (Peter George) that the movie is based on.  (In the novel the bomber misses its target, the bombs fizzle, and nuclear catastrophe is averted.)

Was this scene wholly invented by Kubrick or Terry Southern (who came in to help rewrite the story as a comedy in late 1962 per [this column by Southern](http://www.visual-memory.co.uk/amk/doc/0081.html)) or was it borrowed?  The reason this question occurs to me is because I discovered a very similar scene in "[Of Earth Foretold](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?681993)," a 1960 novella by Kenneth Bulmer:

> The second pair . . .
>
> One hung up.
>
> [...] He went scrabbling out along the supporting rail, his wrench ready, everything in him aimed at knocking that release clamp over and getting rid of the capsule.
>
> He swung the wrench in a calculated, skilful blow. The release resisted. He tried again, slamming the wrench in hard. [...]
>
> One more good hard shrewd knock—the wrench slammed again at the clamp. It must have been partially freed by his earlier blows. He had used far too much power. The clamp flipped over smoothly and the wrench savaged around, pulling his arm with it, twisting his shoulder in the spacesuit, tugging at him.
>
> Clumsy in the big suit he toppled off the rail.
>
> Without thought, the black fear in him blanking all reason, he hooked one arm and leg into the capsule's handling rings.
>
> Capsule and man went out the bomb bay together.

Granted that the scene is not played for humor here, the similarity is obvious.

"Of Earth Foretold" appeared in *Science Fiction Adventures*, No. 14, May 1960 and was expanded to novel length as [*The Earth Gods are Coming*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?4288), Ace Double #D-453 (also 1960) and then released standalone as [*Of Earth Foretold*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?285035) in 1961.  So there were several opportunities for it to be read before the rewrite of *Dr. Strangelove* that introduced the bomb scene.  Note particularly that both the initial publication and the standalone novel were released in the U.K. where the rewrite and the movie's filming took place.

This question is interesting because the TV Tropes page [Riding the Bomb](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RidingTheBomb) lists *Dr. Strangelove* as the Trope Maker and doesn't even mention *Of Earth Foretold*.

Obviously at least Southern has described some of the process of (re)writing the movie, so it's quite possible there are other accounts that might shed some light on this.  The [Wikipedia page for the movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Strangelove) has a few details of the timeline of the rewrite, but doesn't get into specific elements.

Comment: Hmm. It's hard to believe Kubrick would have spent much of his time reading obscure stories in second-tier sci-fi pulps, but the alternative is that he would have to have thought up that scene by himself, and when you've eliminated the impossible . . .

Comment: And George Lucas must have read Mari Wolf's story "Robots of the World! Arise!" in the July 1952 issue of *If*, where else could he have got the idea to call robots "droids"?

Comment: I've wondered if the idea of having Yoda speak in English words with scrambled word order was inspired by the Voltamen's speech in the *Lost World* saga in *Planet Comics*.

Comment: @user14111 I'm not going to say you're wrong, but I didn't know of a prior example before I discovered "Of Earth Foretold," and the timing and events are very close.  And most of the immediately subsequent appearances were acknowledgments (e.g. parodies) of the *Dr. Strangelove* scene.  So, 15+ years after WWII and 10 years into the nuclear cold war we have 2 independent appearances of the same idea within 2 years of one another...  I thought it enough of a coincidence to ask about.